# PostgreSQL: Syntax error at or near "14" when trying to run a delete query

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

First question here!

So I have a table with a row like this:

```sql
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I would like to run a query that delete all the data in my table older than 14 days.

This is my query:

```sql
DELETE FROM customers WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY;
```

This is the error: syntax error at or near "14"

Anyone knows why this is not working and/or how could I achieve my goal??

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The interval value must be quoted:

```sql
DELETE FROM customers WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAYS';
```

See [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: @LucaTomarelli: Instead of addin a "Thanks!" comment, it is custom here to upvote and/or accept an answer if it helped...

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '14 DAY';
```

Comment: @LucaTomarelli: Instead of addin a "Thanks!" comment, it is custom here to upvote and/or accept an answer if it helped...

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on the existing answers (possibly easier to remember):

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE timestamp < NOW() - '14 days'::interval;
```